# React JS Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): item.persistVariablesLimit.trim is not a function

Tags: reactjs, variables, undefined, default

I'm getting the following error:

```
React JS Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): item.persistVariablesLimit.trim is not a function
```

when I try to set a default value on the persistVariablesLimit.

Here is an image of the stack trace and console log:

[image: error display]

Here's the code that generates it:

```
    if (typeof item.persistVariablesLimit !== 'undefined') {
        item.persistVariablesLimit = item.persistVariablesLimit.trim()
        if (!item.persistVariablesLimit.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
            formIsValid = false
            errors['persistVariablesLimit'] = 'Must be numeric'
        }
    }
```

There is no problem with this field if the data is entered manually, even if it is entered, then deleted.

Also, if I don't set a default value, and don't enter anything into the field, it is saved successfully as an empty string.

Here's where it sets the default value (when the "FA" template is selected):

```
handleSelectTemplateChange = (event, { value }) => {
    let item = { ...this.state.item }
    item.template = value
var str1 = '' + item.template

if (str1.startsWith('SMA')) {
    item.family = 'Safety-Machine-Analytics'
}
if (str1.startsWith('FA')) {
    item.family = 'Field Analytics'
    item.product = 'Field Analytics'
    if (!item.persistVariablesLimit) {
        item.persistVariablesLimit = 50;
    }
    if (!item.dataSourceLimit) {
        item.dataSourceLimit = 50;
    }
}
else {
        item.persistVariablesLimit = "";
        item.dataSourceLimit = "";
}


this.setState({ item })
}
```

This is the UI code for the template:

```
                    <Form.Select
                        fluid
                        label='Template'
                        options={this.state.templateOptions || []}
                        placeholder='Template'
                        name='template'
                        value={item.template}
                        required={true}
                        onChange={this.handleSelectTemplateChange}
                    />
```

And for the persistVariableLimit field:

```
                    <Form.Input
                        label='Persist Variables Limit'
                        placeholder='Persist Variables Limit'
                        name='persistVariablesLimit'
                        value={item.persistVariablesLimit || ''}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        required={false}
                        disabled={false}
                        error={this.state.errors['persistVariablesLimit']}
                    />
```

This is an item originally retrieved from an API. It's initialized as follows:

```
emptyItem = {
    fullName: '',
    contact: '',
    requester: '',
    tag: '',
    company: '',
    companyId: '',
    product: '',
    expiration: '',
    macsArray: '',
    dashboardIDs: '',
    typeId: '',
    family: '',
    systems: '',
    fileName: '',
    url: '',
    attributesArray: [],
    persistVariablesLimit: '',
    dataSourceLimit: ''
} 

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const { cookies } = props

this.state = {
    item: this.emptyItem,
    csrfToken: cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'),
    fields: {},
    errors: {}
}
...
```

}

Here's the API call:

```
    if (this.props.match.params.id !== 'new') {
        try {
            const tmpLicense = await (await fetch(API_HOST + `/api/license/${this.props.match.params.id}`, { credentials: 'include' })).json()

            this.setState({ item: tmpLicense })

        } catch (error) {
            this.props.history.push('/')
        }
```

How should I be setting this default value? What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re setting the default values as numbers, `.trim` is a String method.

It should be:

```
    if (!item.persistVariablesLimit) {
        item.persistVariablesLimit = '50';
    }
    if (!item.dataSourceLimit) {
        item.dataSourceLimit = '50';
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the variable type is defined by the variable you set it with then. Interesting, and something I never really got until now.